# javascript Unexpected token else

Tags: javascript

Someone please help what is wrong in the following code. It is saying "Unexpected token else" while validating javascript code on [Java Validate website - esprima.org](http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html)

`

```
function add1()
{
 var size = 8;
 var widthOfGrid = size;
 var lenthOfGrid = size;
 var linenumber = 1;
 for (i = 1 ; i<=size ; i += 1 )
   {
    for (j = 1 ; j<=size ; j += 1)
      {
       If (i % 2 === 0)
        {
          console.log(" " +  "#");
        }
        else
        {
         console.log("#" + " ");
        }
       }
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript there is no `If` statement. Javascript is a `case-sensitive` language Write it in the `lower case` - `if`. And also refactor your code, you have some unused variables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `If` should be lowercase.

The code should be like this:

```
function add1() {
    var size = 8;
    var widthOfGrid = size;
    var lenthOfGrid = size;
    var linenumber = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= size; i += 1) {
        for (j = 1; j <= size; j += 1) {
            if(i % 2 === 0)
            {
                console.log(" " + "#");
            }
        else
            {
                console.log("#" + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function add1()
{
 var size = 8;
 var widthOfGrid = size;
 var lenthOfGrid = size;
 var linenumber = 1;
 for (i = 1 ; i<=size ; i += 1 )
   {
    for (j = 1 ; j<=size ; j += 1)
      {
       if (i % 2 === 0)
        {
          console.log(" " +  "#");
        }
        else
        {
         console.log("#" + " ");
        }
       }
    }
}
```

working code,you forget make your if in lowercase